# PHP doesn't show some characters properly

Tags: php, character-encoding

I am running a PHP CLI script on my local machine, which calls an API and receives back UTF encoded string. Now, this string is basically a simple word in Portuguese, and I can see it properly when printed on the screen(terminal). However, on a different machine, some characters are not shown properly. The question is, which php.ini option would I need to set in order to see string properly on the other machine? I haven't touched my PHP.ini in regards to encoding and everything works fine, so I'm not sure what do I need to enable for UTF to work on a php cli app?

Edit: this should not be a terminal issue. To be more specific, API returns back a string(UTF encoded) which is supposed to be found inside an array. However, PHP is issuing a warning on another machine saying that can't find that string inside an array. It is the key doesn't exist error that I'm getting, and the key or the string that is shown doesn't look right, so that's the case.

It is basically

```
$stringReturnedFromApi = $apiCall();
$this->myArray[$stringReturnedFromApi];
```

it works right on my machine, on another is complaining that the key doesn't exist, and when I looked up `$stringReturnedFromAp`, it doesn't look UTF encoded

Comment: Is the other machine using the same kind of terminal?

Comment: Yes, pretty much everything is the same expect PHP.

Comment: Please provide us with some minimal code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: It is basically $stringReturnedFromApi = $apiCall();  $this->myArray[$stringReturnedFromApi], it works right on my machine, on another is complaining that the key doesn't exist, and when I lookup $stringReturnedFromAp, it doesn't look UTF encoded

Answer (score 0):

The other terminals need to be set to UTF-8 encoding. For instance, PuTTY needs to be told what encoding, or he will use (on windows) ANSI if i remember well.

If the other host is not on Windows, just verify the locales to be sure it is UTF-8. This is not on your side that the error is, this is just an encoding which is client-side.

If the result is printed out to a webpage, be sure the charset encoding is set to UTF8 also;

Comment: I have updated the questions with more details, thanks.

Comment: are you explicitly sending utf8_encode("value") from the server, or do you just send "value" with a header specifying the character_encoding ?

Comment: The server is a remote machine that I don't have access to. I can see that response header contains Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8 . So I've tried to simulate this behavior on my local machine, by disabling first mbstring extension and then setting default_charset="", and it still works fine. So, I really don't know that is the problem with the PHP on the second machine.

Comment: can you confirm that the other machine is running with a charset .UTF-8 ? (not php, the machine itself, the "locale")

Comment: I can't at the moment, but I can try setting locale to non-utf on my local machine in order to simulate the same behavior. So I did it: LANG=en_IN. Now I can confirm that I don't have UTF locale set, default_charset PHP setting is empty, and I don't have mbstring extension enabled, and UTF encoding still works on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is actually a PHP problem.

Without seeing your script I can't say anything 100%, but I am guessing that the PHP script is actually correctly outputting the UTF character.  The reason it looks odd is because the terminal doesn't understand UTF encoding and is unable to display the character.

You would need to be a little more specific on the details of the terminal application you are using to determine where the actual problem lies.  I doubt it is something you can fix in the php.ini

Comment: Please.....if you are _only guessing_ so put your _guess_ into a comment instead of misusing the answer section..thanks

Comment: I have updated the questions with more details, thanks.

Comment: You are still not being precice enough.  UTF on it's own isn't telling us enough.  Where character encoding is concerned you need to ensure both servers are configured for the exact same encoding or one will display characters differently to the other.